# Float Tiff image to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tiff

I have the problem that I have a float image (*.tif) with values from 0-1 and want to use this in my python program as a numpy array. But every module I've found so far that is capable of reading .tif converts it into a UINT8 which comes with information loss.

Comment: [tifffile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tifffile) handles float TIFFs, but I've never used it and I don't know what it does with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large tiff images you can try to use [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) library for geospatial data.

```
with rasterio.open('/path/to/your/image.tif') as src:
    bands = src.read()
```

the data type is inferred from the input image.

Comment: I know the problem is that Image.open() already converted it from float32 to uint8. So yes I can convert it from there back to float32 but this would result in 255 -> 255. not staying at let's say 0.3456947.

Comment: maybe you can call [`PIL.Image.frombytes`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes). But you have to know the [_modes_](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes) and the _shape_ of the image. 

    `from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np

    image_pil = Image.frombytes(mode, shape, open(image).read())
    image_array = np.asarray(image_pil)`

Comment: raise ValueError("not enough image data")
ValueError: not enough image data

Comment: maybe you inserted the wrong modes? you can try with rasterio!

Comment: The mode is "F" for 32bit floating point pixels, isn't it? Also what options would you use with rasterio as open still only gives [uint8] values even with given dtype of np.float32

Comment: I tested the rasterio library with a float32 tiff image from the example library of GDAL. It imports the image as float32!